# How to use my webhost's mailserver to send emails with my app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, email, heroku, smtp

I am building an application in NodeJS using Heroku to manage it. I chose Heroku because of its scalabiliy, ease of use, addons, and integration with Git.

I happen to have a webhosting account with Bluehost, and it includes a mail server.

I want to send emails from my application but Heroku doesn't offer a mail server (yes there are some addons, but they generally cost money). I want to use the mail server I have with Bluehost to send emails on behalf of my app.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Can you explain why/why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw this. I suppose you could just create a php form on bluehost that takes post parameters for where to send the email and the email contents. Then just send it using php on bluehost. To do this you would have to make a post request to your webserver on bluehost from your nodejs app.